# Is clang's is_trivially_copyable incorrect for this case?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I am implementing my own optional type to get familiar with C++20 concepts and to have a C++20-compatible version of the and_then, or_else and transform functions for hobby projects. This is my first time working with C++20. I bumped up against the following ([godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/6b5jr67q5)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct Optional
{
    constexpr Optional() = default;

    constexpr Optional(const Optional &) requires std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>
    = default;

    constexpr Optional(const Optional &other) requires(!std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>)
        : m_payload(other.m_payload.x)
    {
    }

  private:
    union Payload
    {
        T x;
    } m_payload;
};

// All good
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<Optional<int>>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Optional<int>>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Optional<int>>);

// Fails on clang-15.0.0 (and several older versions)
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Optional<int>>);
```

I believe this is incorrect behavior from clang. I suspect the issue is the wording "each eligible copy constructor is trivial" in the requirements for a trivially copyable class - but the second copy constructor I don't think should be considered an "eligible copy constructor". MSVC and gcc both agree with me.

Can anyone confirm that this should be considered a bug with clang?

Comment: "*and to have a C++20-compatible version of the and_then, or_else and transform functions for hobby projects*" It'd be way easier to write them as free functions invoked on a `std::optional<T>`. They don't *have to be* members.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good point. I omitted an additional reason, which is I want to be able to have `optional<T&>`. But mostly it's for the experience of implementing a - relatively simple - piece of standard library functionality.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [C++ Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20) page, [P0848R3](https://wg21.link/P0848R3) is not supported prior to Clang 16 (and its support in Clang 16 is not complete). This is the C++20 feature in which certain language rules that refer to copy constructors (such as the definition of "trivially copyable") are changed to apply only to *eligible* copy constructors, in case there are multiple ones with the same argument type that differ in their constraints. (It also has similar provisions for other special member functions.)

GCC and MSVC are right. Your version of Clang is too old.